# How do I write characters to the console without line breaks?

Tags: c#, console, console.writeline

```
  string value = "test";             
         for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
         {                
             Console.WriteLine(value[i]);

         }
```

output of the program is:

```
t
e
s
t
```

I want the output would be "test"

Comment: Just do `Console.WriteLine(value);`

Comment: If you want to output the whole string, then why are iterating over its individual characters in the first place?

Comment: I want to concatenate individual character so that it makes string.

Comment: The value is already "test". No need for concatenation here. Or just use Write instead to output one character at a time to the console.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Console.Write()`

```
string value = "test";             
     for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
     {                
         Console.Write(value[i]);

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop at all:

```
string value = "test"; 
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason as to why your output is printing on a different line is because of `Console.WriteLine`..

That needs to be changed to `Console.Write`

so the in the body of your *for loop*:

```
Console.Write(value[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Char Array instead of String, if you want to concentrate on each character.
But I would like to join my previous speakers to use

```
 Console.Write(value);
```

Please keep in mind, that your string has already the value *test* and there is no need to iterate through each char.